# Sinon - returns is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I'm writing unit tests and I have a module file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

const bulkUpdateDependencies = (outdatedPackages) => {
    // some logic
    return ({});
};

module.exports = bulkUpdateDependencies;
```

In the test file I require it but when I try to do this:

```
const bulkUpdateDependencies = require('../src/bulk-update-dependencies');

bulkUpdateDependenciesStub = sandbox.stub(bulkUpdateDependencies);
bulkUpdateDependenciesStub.returns({});
```

I get this:

> bulkUpdateDependencies.returns is not a function

Please advise on how do I properly stub `bulkUpdateDependencies` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to stub a standalone function directly. Here is the solution:

`bulk-update-dependencies.js`:

```js
const bulkUpdateDependencies = (outdatedPackages) => {
  return {};
};

module.exports = bulkUpdateDependencies;
```

`bulk-update-dependencies.spec.js`:

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("59435659", () => {
  let sandbox;
  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should pass", () => {
    const bulkUpdateDependenciesStub = sandbox.stub().returns("stubbed data");
    require.cache[require.resolve("./bulk-update-dependencies.js")] = {
      exports: bulkUpdateDependenciesStub,
    };
    const bulkUpdateDependencies = require("./bulk-update-dependencies.js");
    const actual = bulkUpdateDependencies();
    expect(actual).to.be.equal("stubbed data");
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(bulkUpdateDependenciesStub);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 59435659
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (7ms)

----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 bulk-update-dependencies.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59435659